# Concurrent updates of relational application data

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, concurrency, relational-database

We have a Qt C++ Gui application that is basically a terminal to a server (TCP) software controlling it and displaying its data.

The problem is that the data coming from the server is highly relational data. 
In SQL Terms it would be ~10-15 tables all interconnected by some foreign keys

This data gets updated by the server and must be (at the same time) displayed by the GUI.

Out current solution is that we store all the data in (basically) maps and structs with the appropriate locking (read/write) to avoid problems of concurrent access.

We now face the problem that this solution doesn't scale very well. The performance of the application (click to something happens on screen latency) gets worse.

Will using an in application relational database system (like sqlite with an in memory database) help? 
Is using a database (where the relational dependencies are solved when querying) better scaling than using maps of structs (where the relational dependencies are solved during insert) ?

I hope I made my problem as clear as possible.

Regards,
Andre

---

To make it more clear: It's about the GUI isn't responsive anymore as many updates from the server lock the datastructures.

Comment: Question: user inputs commands in the GUI, which are then sent to the server, which responds with more data (based on the query)?

Comment: I fear that with "locking" you mean send a lock request from client to server, respond with a lock success/fail, and on success continue with the update? Because that explains the slowness.

Comment: Ah ok, still unclear ... Ignore what the client is doing to the server. It's all about the data that is coming from the server. Processing the data (putting it into the correct maps) essentially blocks the GUI thread from drawing.
An therefor the question: will a RDB help in this case

Comment: No, it will not. Data is coming in "raw" form: you'll have translation to SQL + `INSERT` + `SELECT` + GUI adaptation overhead just to display something. Use a thread for data collection then alert the GUI.

Comment: We currently _are_ using multiple threads (1 for GUI drawing) and an event thread to process incoming events. But the locking of the datastructures is killing our performance here.

Comment: What about trying 1 thread per table? Those should be unrelated. However, I would rely on profiling for this

Comment: Before offering such solutions, you really should check your assumptions first. How many locks do you have? If there's a single big lock, multiple threads won't help at all. All but one would be waiting on that lock. That could even make things worse: the GUI thread wouldn't get the lock for 1/2 of the time, but only 1/N.

Comment: From the question, it seems to me that many locks are used ("maps and structs with the appropriate locking"). Don't know for sure.

Comment: I think that you need to actually try it out with sqlite and see if it's any faster. [Here's a description of sqlite3's locking in v3](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Answer (score 3):

(Based on the updated comment stating the actual problem, UI thread block)

There are two simple fixes that can help here. The first problem is to preprocess all the incoming data before locking the shared data structures. For instance, if you have `std::string` in a map, don't convert `const char*` to `std::string` while holding a lock on the map. That's going to call `strlen` while holding up the UI thread. Instead, convert first and then lock the map.

The second improvement is to lock the GUI for a smaller amount of time. If the update can be partitioned in multiple smaller parts, take and release the lock repeatedly. This will mean the actual update is slower, but the UI more responsive.

A more complicated strategy (if partitioning isn't possible) is staging. Create all the new entries in a new map, and then merge the two maps. This is basically preprocessing on steroids, as you now also sort the new entries.
(I hope you're exchanging diffs with the server, and not doing full refreshes of the data each time!)

Comment: Good Ideas. We are doing delta-updates but have a significant amount of (what we call) initial updates ... All the delta updates up to this point. This happens during a reconnect mid-day.

Comment: Preparing the updates prior to adding to a container is what we are already doing (in the form of shared pointers). But to make sure that the relational contrains hold we still have to lock multiple container. (So that the reader won't see a broken state)

Comment: @Bigbohne: Guaranteeing referential integrity is a database responsibility, not a UI responsibility. I hope you're not spending time blocking the UI thread to guarantee such integrity? It may even be worth to have two copies of the data, one for the UI and one for the delta updates. After each update, make a copy of the fresh data (at that time, the third copy), lock, swap the copy with the UI's copy (this is instant - root node pointer swap), unlock, and discard the old UI data.